# How do I create a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` with a single thread without using the `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor`?

Tags: java, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

How do I create a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` with a single thread without using the `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor` ?

The reason I want to do so is that the later call returns an instance of `DelegatedScheduledExecutorService` and not an instance of `ThreadPoolExecutor` , so my attempts to be able to use methods such as `getQueue()` etc fails. If I can create a `ThreadPoolExecutor` directly that would help.

And the reason I want to `getQueue()` is that there is no other way to know the size of the tasks currently queued up in the executor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [constructor of ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor%28int%29).

Comment: I mean to have a ThreadPool of a single thread **at MAX**. This ctr will allow as many threads as required.

Comment: No. The javadoc says: *While this class inherits from ThreadPoolExecutor, a few of the inherited tuning methods are not useful for it. In particular, because it acts as a fixed-sized pool using corePoolSize threads and an unbounded queue, adjustments to maximumPoolSize have no useful effect.* As @assylias said, `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool()` calls this constructor.

Comment: I got confused by the constructors on `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` - they take a Integer.MAX as the value of Maximum no. of threads in threadpool when calling `super()` , but then  it calls `addIfUnderCorePoolSize` - which makes it now clear. I should have read the doc.

Answer (score 1):

You can create it manually (that's what `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool()` does under the hood, except that you would need a cast to use the returned object the way you want):

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduler = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
BlockingQueue q = scheduler.getQueue();
```

Comment: I mean to have a ThreadPool of a single thread **at MAX**. This ctr will allow as many threads as required.